# how to calculate the spectrum and inertia of sign pattern matrix?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

I want to know how to calculate the spectrum and inertia of sign pattern matrix, how to use Nilpotent-Jacobian method to solve the problem about determinating spectrally arbitrary and inertially arbitrary sign patterns ?

Comment: A more specific question might be better, since a satisfactory answer to your question would require pages out of a textbook.

Comment: The problem is about sign pattern matrix in combinatorial matrix theory. The knowledge is mainly used to solve spectrally arbitrary and inertially arbitrary sign pattern matrices.